# Are all indecomposable $\mathbb{Z}_+$-modules over the character ring of a group, character rings of a subgroup?

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, modules

A $\mathbb Z_+$-algebra is an algebra $A$ over $\mathbb C$ with given basis $\{v_i\}$ such that
$$v_iv_j=\sum_k n_{ijk}v_k,\hspace{10mm}n_{ijk}\in\mathbb Z_{\geq0}.$$
An example of such an object is the *character ring* of a group $G$, given by $\mathbb C[\chi_\rho\ |\ \rho\in\mathrm{Irr} G]$.

A $\mathbb Z_+$-module over $A$ is a module $M$ over $A$ with given basis $\{m_i\}$ such that
$$v_im_j=\sum_k n_{ijk}'m_k,\hspace{10mm}n_{ijk}'\in\mathbb Z_{\geq0}.$$
If $H\subset G$ is a subgroup, then the character ring of $H$ becomes a $\mathbb Z_+$-module over the character ring of $G$, by restriction to $H$. (so for $\rho\in\mathrm{Irr} G$ and $\sigma\in\mathrm{Irr} H$, we have $\chi_\rho\cdot\chi_\sigma=\chi_\rho\vert_{H}\cdot\chi_\sigma$)

Direct sums of $\mathbb Z_+$-modules is just the direct sum of modules, and the basis is the union of the bases. A $\mathbb Z_+$-module is said to be indecopmosable if it is not the direct sum of nonzero $\mathbb Z_+$-modules.

Now my question is this:

> Are all indecomposable $\mathbb Z_+$-modules of the character ring of $G$ of the form above: so the character ring of a subgroup $H$ of $G$?

The reason I believe this is true is because a more categorial version of this is proved in EGNO's Tensor Categories, Corollary 7.12.20, but I don't understand their proof as it refers to 3 other theorems, which themselves each refer to other theorems and so on. I also think that a proof just in terms of $\mathbb Z_+$-algebras would be easier, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: This was re-posted from Math.SE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4720523/are-all-indecomposable-mathbbz-modules-over-the-character-ring-of-a-group

Answer (score 5):

I do not think this is true. Let $G = A_{5}$, let $A$ denote the character ring of $G$. Let $M$ denote the $\mathbb{C}$-span of the Brauer characters of $G$ for the prime $2$, (extended to take the value $0$ on all $2$-singular elements).

Then $M$ has a $\mathbb{C}$-basis containing 4 class functions $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta$, defined as follows: $\alpha$ takes the value $1$ on elements of odd order, and $0$ on elements of even order. The function $\beta$ takes value $2$ on the identity, $-1$ on elements of order $3$, $\omega + \omega^{-1}$ ( where $\omega = e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{5}}$) on one conjugacy class of elements of order $5$, $\omega^{2} + \omega^{-2}$ on the other class of elements of order $5$, and $0$ on elements of even order. The function $\gamma$  is algebraically conjugate to (and different from) $\beta$. The function $\delta$ takes the value $4$ on the identity, $1$ on elements of order $3$, $-1$ on elements of order $5$, $0$ on elements of even order.

Because $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta$ are essentially (irreducible) Brauer characters, it follows that for any irreducible character $\chi$ of $G$, each of $\chi \alpha, \chi \beta, \chi \gamma, \chi \delta$ is a non-negative integer combination of
$\{\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta\}.$
Then $M$ is an indecomposable $\mathbb{Z}_{+}$-module for $A$, but is not the character ring of a subgroup of $G$.